Wordpress migration and problem with homepage
this is my very first time asking something here!
I'm currently working on building a website for an association.
Due to things unrelevant to explain here, people I work with have built our new website on a temporary address (let's call it domain-a.com). Meanwhile other people bought the right domain ( domain-b.com) on Ionos and paid for the All-In-One Migration unlimited extension and now I'm in charge of dealing with it all.
I need to transfer everything done on domain-a.com to domain-b.com which is an empty website.
I used the plugin, everything looks good EXCEPT my homepage.
See, if I am logged in, I can see the right homepage, that is the one from domain-a.com.
But when I go on incognito mode or ask friends, I see the default homepage that was on domain-b.com prior to the migration.
I waited over 3 hours, I have cleared the entire cache using another plugin (before and after the migration). I have tried over, reseting the wordpress to be sure there wasn't even a homepage to begin with but it doesn't change a thing.
I am currently at loss at what to do because all the rest seems good, it's  really just this homepage issue. Thanks for your help guys!
